# use symfony form validator for Bulk-Insert

Tags: validation, forms, symfony1, memory-management, bulkinsert

i receive an CSV File from the User and I want to insert it into the Database. I want to use the Form Validation:

```
$pf = new ProductForm();
$old_memory_usage = 0;

while($data = $csvreader->read())
{
  $mem = memory_get_usage() / 1024;
  echo "Memory-Usage: " . $mem . " KB; Mem-Diff: " . $mem - $old_memory_usage . "\n";
  $old_memory_usage = $mem;

  $p = new Product();
  $p->fromArray($data);
  $pf->bind($p->toArray(), array());
  if($pf->isValid())
  {
    $p->save();
  }
  else
  {
    //display error message to the user
  }
}
```

This works fine when isValid() returns true. The Memory Difference is 0 KB. But if there is an Error in the "form" the memory-difference is 6-7 KB. So I get an allowed_memory error when the CSV-File is very huge.

I tryed to free the form like:

```
unset($pf)
$pf = null;
$pf = new ProductForm();
```

no success. It is just worse!

ans ideas?
thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable doctrine profiler in your databse yml:

```
  dev:
    doctrine:
      class: sfDoctrineDatabase
      param:
        profiler: false
```

Comment: There is no difference with profiler set to false. still 6-7KB... :(

Comment: yes, but if you try a bulk insert, the memeory consumed by doctrine is very low with no profiler...

Comment: I think this is not the problem. The memory-difference is 0 when the form is valid. Otherwise 6-7 KB and after a few thousand rows it reach the memory limit.

Comment: The doBind method use sfeventDispatcher to notify errors... http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfFormSymfony#method_dobind it could be the origin of the memory leak on errors. Maybe you can to oeveride this method.

Comment: I found a way: $pf->getValidator($fieldname)->clean($field_csv_value) and catch a sfValidatorError